# Messages.app is not synchronizing on my apple ID

Tags: macos, icloud, messages

I am logged into the iCloud account and Messages.app was working on another macbook pro for me. This one is missing something.

The "@iMessage" panel shows the correct information

[image]

But on "General" if clicking on "Set up name and photo sharing" I see:

> Sharing Name and Photo is not available because iCloud and iMessage accounts are different or are not signed in

[image]

What else needs to be done here?  This is an older 2015 laptop on *Big Sur*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be only a partial answer but it does allow to set the name of the linked messages user.

It is necessary to configure the "Apple ID" configurator in *System Preferences*.

[image]

It is a complicated ordeal to configure it seems.  I am partially through that configuration.  *Messages* are still not synchronizing from iCloud.

**Update**  Messages are now getting synchronized. I think the additional piece to the puzzle is to completely logout or reboot.